# SELECT CASE STATEMENT

Tags: case, sql-server-2014

Here I have a few doctype which based on acctype. Like below sql.

```
CASE docType 
   WHEN 'I' THEN 'INVOICE' 
   WHEN 'M' THEN 'INVOICE' 
   WHEN 'D' THEN 'DEBIT NOTE' 
   WHEN 'C' THEN 'CREDIT NOTE' 
   WHEN 'P' THEN 'SUPPLIER INVOICE' 
   WHEN 'N' THEN 'SUPPLIER CREDIT NOTE' 
   ELSE '' 
END as docType
```

How I want to differentiate, `if doctype = I,M,D,C = Customer, else = supplier`

I tried to do like this

```
SELECT
    CASE 
       WHEN (docType = 'I' OR docType = 'M' OR docType = 'D' OR docType = 'C') 
          THEN 'CUSTOMER' 
          ELSE 'SUPPLIER' 
    END as accType 
FROM
    AccountDoc
```

but the result does not filter the acctype

Answer (score 0):

You can query like that:

```
SELECT CASE  
  WHEN docType IN ('I', 'M', 'D', 'C')
        THEN 'CUSTOMER'
        ELSE 'SUPPLIER'
        END as accType
  FROM AccountDoc
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
select (case when (docType = 'I' OR docType = 'M' OR docType = 'D' OR docType = 'C')
    then 'Customer'
    else 'Supplier' end )
    as accType 
from AccountDoc
```